# Does this condition on the curvature implies existence of a parallel section?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, curvature, connections

Let $E$ be a smooth vector bundle over a manifold $M$ ($\dim M>1$), equipped with a metric. Let $\nabla$ be a metric connection on $E$.

> Suppose there exist locally a non-zero section $\sigma \in \Gamma(E)$ which lies in $\ker R(X,Y)$ for **all** $X,Y \in \Gamma(TM)$. Does $\nabla$ admit a parallel section (locally)?

Note that even if $\| \sigma\|=1$, it is not necessarily true that $\sigma$ parallel. (e.g. if $\nabla$ is flat).

(We have to normalize: the point is that if $\sigma \in \ker R(X,Y)$ so is $f\sigma$ for any function $f$. A parallel section has a constant norm though.)

*Clearly, this is a necessary condition:*

If $\sigma$ is parallel, then
$R(X,Y)\sigma=d_{\nabla}^2\sigma(X,Y)=0$

Comment: Notice that (Ambrose-Singer theorem, see e.g. Kobayashi-Nomizu's book) endomorphisms of the form $Z\mapsto R(X,Y)Z$ span the Lie algebra of the holonomy group of the connection. Hence, the reduced holonomy group $H_p$ of your connection has a fixed nonzero vector $v\in E_p$. Now, parallel-translate this vector in a small neighborhood of $p$. The result is the required parallel section.

Comment: Thank you. By the reduced holonomy group do you refer to restriction to contractible loops? (sometimes this is called the *reduced* holonomy group $\text{Hol}^0$, right?). I don't understand why the exponential map should be surjective on $\text{Hol}^0$: If I understood correctly, your argument is the following: Let $G \le \text{GL}(n)$ be a Lie subgroup and $\mathfrak{g} \le M_n$ be its Lie algebra. We assume that $v \in M_n$ satisfies $Av=0$ for every $A \in \mathfrak{g} $. Then $e^{tA} v=v$ for every $A \in \mathfrak{g} $...

Comment: Now, we need to know that the exponential map of $\exp:\mathfrak{g} \to G$ is surjective, in order to conclude that $Gv=v$. In our case,  $\text{Hol}$ is contained in $O(n)$ since our connection is metric, but I don't see why this implies that $\exp$ is surjective, as $\text{Hol}^0$ might not be closed inside $\text{Hol}$, right? (I know surjectivity of $\exp$ is automatic only when the group is compact...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the reduced holonomy group $Hol^0_p=G$ of $\nabla$ ($p$ is a point in $M$), i.e. the subgroup of the full holonomy group whose elements are defined via parallel transport along null-homotopic loops based at $p$. This is a connected subgroup of the holonomy group. According to Ambrose-Singer theorem (see e.g. Kobayashi-Nomizu's book) endomorphisms of the fiber $E_p$ of the form $Z\mapsto R(X,Y)Z$ span the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ of $G$. Let $Z$ be a nonzero local section of $E\to M$ near $p$ such that $R(X,Y)Z=0$ for all local sections $X, Y$ of $E\to M$ near $p$. Define the (nonzero) vector $v\in E_p$, $v=Z(p)$. Exponentiating the Lie algebra, we obtain an open neighborhood $U$ of $e\in G$ whose elements fix $v$ (since, by the assumption, $R(X,Y)Z=0$ for all local sections $X, Y$). Let $H$ denote the subgroup of $G$ generated by $U$. Then $H$ is an open subgroup of $G$ which fixes $v$. However, it is also a closed subgroup of $G$ (every open subgroup of a topological group is also closed, this is a nice exercise). Since $G$ is connected, $H=G$. Thus, the entire group $G$ fixes $v$. Now, parallel-translate $v$ in a small (simply-connected) neighborhood $V$ of $$: Since $v$ is fixed by $G$, the parallel transport is independent of the path in $V$. The result is a nonzero local parallel section of $E\to M$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Just to be sure then: By the same argument, can we conclude that the dimension of the space of *local* parallel sections of $(E,\nabla)$ equals to the dimension of the kernel of the Lie algebra of $Hol^0$? i.e. there exist $k$ independent local parallel sections $\sigma_i$ of $E$ if and only if there exist $k$ independent local sections $\sigma_i$ satisfying $R(\cdot,\cdot)\sigma_i=0$. Am I right?

Comment: @AsafShachar: Right.